# two points inside a ball centered at a point in the unit sphere.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Take $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $||x||=1$ and $r>0$. Suppose that $y\in B_r(x)$ then $\frac{y}{||y||}\in B_r(x)$

I don't really know how to bound in the correct way this quantity:

$$\left|\left|x-\displaystyle\frac{y}{||y||}\right|\right| $$

any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite get the question.  Are you asking for conditions that imply $y/\|y\|\in B_r(x)$ or what?  Certainly if $r\ge2$ this will hold, but not always if $r<2$.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Notice that  $y/\|y\|$ always has norm $1$ and so, for example if $x$ is large (norm larger than $2$), then $x \in B_r(x)$ [as always] but $x / \|x \| \not \in B_r(x)$.

Comment: But in the hypothesis I have that $||x||=1$.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality on the norm to find it is bounded by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced the statement is true. Note that the points $x,y,\frac{y}{\Vert y\Vert}$ determine a plane which intersects the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a circle. In the following Geogebra construction the red circle is where that plane intersects the unit sphere and the dotted blue line is where the boundary of the open ball of radius $r$ about $x$ intersects the plane containing $x,y,\frac{y}{\Vert y\Vert}$.

Note that while $y$ lies inside the blue circle, $\frac{y}{\Vert y\Vert}$ lies outside.

[image]

Comment: You are right. Thanks for show me my mistake.

Comment: You are welcome. It was an interesting conjecture.